# calculating change (over a period) for a dated field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE sales_data (
     sales_time date NOT NULL,
     product_id integer NOT NULL,
     sales_amt double NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE date_dimension (
  id integer  NOT NULL,
  datestamp   date NOT NULL,
  day_part    integer NOT NULL,
  week_part   integer NOT NULL,
  month_part  integer NOT NULL,
  qtr_part    integer NOT NULL, 
  year_part   integer NOT NULL, 
);
```

I want to write two types of queries that will allow me to calculate:

- period on period change (e.g. week on week change)
- change in period on period change (e.g. change in week on week change)

I would prefer to write this in ANSI SQL, since I dont want to be tied to any particular db.

**[Edit]**

In light of some of the comments, if I have to be tied to a single database (in terms of SQL dialect), it will have to be PostgreSQL

The queries I want to write are of the form (pseudo SQL of course):

```
Query Type 1 (Period on Period Change)
=======================================
a). select product_id, ((sd2.sales_amt - sd1.sales_amt)/sd1.sales_amt) as week_on_week_change from sales_data sd1, sales_data sd2, date_dimension dd where {SOME CRITERIA)

b). select product_id, ((sd2.sales_amt - sd1.sales_amt)/sd1.sales_amt) as month_on_month_change from sales_data sd1, sales_data sd2, date_dimension dd where {SOME CRITERIA)


Query Type 2  (Change in Period on Period Change)
=================================================
a). select product_id, ((a2.week_on_week_change - a1.week_on_week_change)/a1.week_on_week_change) as change_on_week_on_week_change from 
(select product_id, ((sd2.sales_amt - sd1.sales_amt)/sd1.sales_amt) as week_on_week_change from sales_data sd1, sales_data sd2, date_dimension dd where {SOME CRITERIA)
as a1), 
(select product_id, ((sd2.sales_amt - sd1.sales_amt)/sd1.sales_amt) as week_on_week_change from sales_data sd1, sales_data sd2, date_dimension dd where {SOME CRITERIA) as a2)
WHERE {SOME OTHER CRITERIA}
```

Comment: Most databases implement date handling differently,each using different functions to manipulate dates.  As a result it is difficult to write an "all database" approach to your question.  Also, I'm not completely sure what you are after, included some sample data and what the expected results would be from the query you want.

Comment: TBH, your schema is already not applicable to all database products. For example, SQL Server 2005 among others does not implement a `date` data type and SQL Server in general does not implement a data type named `double` although it does implement an equivalent called `float`.

Comment: @Thomas, SQL Server 2008 has a `date` data type as well as a `time` data type, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx, but again, this just shows how different each database and even the version of a database can be.

Comment: @KM. I'm aware of 2008's new features which is why I mentioned 2005 specifically. I completely agree that trying to make something perfectly ANSI compliant only works in theoretical problems and not practical ones.

Comment: As I read it, this question is hardly about dates at all, since the poster is using a date dimension table. The fact table should really just link to the date dimension table's id rather than having a date value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL 8.4 has window functions which can help to calculate period-on-period change without needing to join a table against itself.

For example, to get a week-on-week comparison:

```
create view week_on_week_sales as
select week_part,
       week_sales,
       lag(week_sales, 1) over(order by week_part) as previous_week_sales
from (select week_part,
             sum(sales_amt) as week_sales
      from sales_data
           join date_dimension 
                on sales_data.sales_time = date_dimension.datestamp
      group by date_dimension.week_part) x
order by week_part
```

Similarly to get the second derivative, you can wrap that in a further subquery:

```
select week_part,
       week_sales - previous_week_sales as change,
       week_sales - previous_week_sales
              - lag(week_sales - previous_week_sales, 1) over(order by week_part)
              as change_in_change
from week_on_week_sales
```

The window syntax is standardised in [SQL:2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2003), I believe. However, implementations are not all the same. For example, SQL Server notably doesn't implement LEAD() and LAG() functions. I tested this on Postgresql 8.4. Oracle supports similar functions (and Postgresql usually follows Oracle), and I believe DB2 also supports these queries although the exact syntax may differ. Others?

Comment: +1 For the code snippet. It is so concise. (Whoo - making my head spin though!). Now to make sure I understand it and to test it on some data then I will accept it as my final answer. Thanks for your help

Comment: if this works, I'd like to give you some bonus points. The code is so elegant, I can't just "take it and run", I know I have less points than you, but I would still like to give you some of my points - seriously, I have been wrestling with this for a LONG time... (is there a way I can give you some of my points to show my gratitude?)

Comment: @morpheous you almost definitely want to read http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html if you haven't already. And depesz's blog post http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2009/01/21/waiting-for-84-window-functions/ is good too. Glad you like it- it seems like all the SQL questions I've answered recently have involved window functions!